# Gyroscope code not displaying values

Tags: android, gyroscope

This is a simple code to get the change in the  values of X,Y and Z axis from the Gyroscope and show them in three text boxes but it is not producing any output. The textboxes remain unchanged. What am I missing?

```
public class Orientation extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
TextView textX, textY, textZ;
SensorManager sensorManager;
Sensor sensor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_orientation);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);


    textX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textX);
    textY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textY);
    textZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textZ);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}


public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int acc) {
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];


    textX.setText("X : " + (int) x + " rad/s");
    textY.setText("Y : " + (int) y + " rad/s");
    textZ.setText("Z : " + (int) z + " rad/s");
}
```

};

EDIT:
Need to check the existence of the sensor first.

Comment: well it will always show 0 rad/s unless you move faster than 1 rad/s which is a pretty fast rotation. Maybe use (int) (x * 100) / 100d instead?

Comment: That's the thing. It doesn't show anything. The textbox remains as it is.

Comment: So the textbox remains empty? Have you tried giving the values out via the LogCat?

Comment: Yup. Plus, I put a simple toast in my onSensorChanged function and it too never pop-ups. Seems the function isn't getting called at all.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working. It seems all pretty right. The only thing that I can imagine being problematic is that you should unregister the listener in onPause instead of in onStop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty extremely lame. The phone didn't have a Gyroscope.